# How to prevent ARP spoofing in local network

Tags: networking, arp

ARP poisoning is rampant in my local network, lucky for those computer that can install programs that defend against it, but not every devices can be installed one such as some smartphones(requires payment), smart devices, Smart Tv, etc.

I was wondering if there is anything i can do in the router level, i have the only access to the router. what should i set to stop this nonesense.

Comment: [Some routers have ARP Spffing Prevention](https://eu.dlink.com/uk/en/support/faq/switches/layer-2-gigabit/dgs-series/es_dgs-1210-seguridad-prevencion-arp-spoofing)

Comment: @DavidPostill Unfortunately the router we have does not have one(Ill keep this in mind though when im pushed to a point where im willing to replace our router), I am curious though how do you know what value you place on the ports field?

Answer (score 0):

First get the mac address of router IP address with `arp -a` command. Then You can use `netsh` to create static ARP entry:

```
netsh interface ipv4 add neighbors "Connection name" <IP address> <Mac Address>
```

Comment: this is for PC's right? The pc is not much of a problem since there are free defenders for it. Not all smart device lets you access the terminals :(

Comment: For android devices you can root it and install Termux for bash like shell